# Sign In With Apple .NET 'Invalid_client' error

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, sign-in-with-apple

I'm trying to set up Sign In With Apple on my .NET 7 Web App. I followed the guide by Scott Brady here: https://www.scottbrady91.com/openid-connect/implementing-sign-in-with-apple-in-aspnet-core

It reaches Apple OK, but when I have logged in, the callback responds with this error.

`OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.`

Googling hasn't helped much, other than I saw a post saying to wait 48 hours, which I have now done (not that that makes sense anyway).

Any idea whats been done wrong? Code below, replacing sensitive data.

**Added to Startup.cs services.AddAuthentication**

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("apple", async options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://appleid.apple.com"; // disco doc: https://appleid.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

        options.ClientId = "com.rackemapp.applelogin"; // Service ID
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-apple"; // corresponding to your redirect URI

        options.ResponseType = "code id_token"; // hybrid flow due to lack of PKCE support
        options.ResponseMode = "form_post"; // form post due to prevent PII in the URL
        options.UsePkce = false; // apple does not currently support PKCE (April 2021)
        options.DisableTelemetry = true;

        options.Scope.Clear(); // apple does not support the profile scope
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("name");
        options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
        {
            context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientSecret = AppleTokenGenerator.CreateNewToken();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

**Apple Token Generator**

```
public static class AppleTokenGenerator
{
    public static string CreateNewToken()
    {
        const string iss = "[MyTeamId]"; // your account's team ID found in the dev portal
        const string aud = "https://appleid.apple.com";
        const string sub = "com.rackemapp.applelogin"; // same as client_id
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // contents of your .p8 file
        const string privateKey = "[MyKey]";
        var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create();
        ecdsa?.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), out _);

        var handler = new JsonWebTokenHandler();
        return handler.CreateToken(new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = iss,
            Audience = aud,
            Claims = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "sub", sub } },
            Expires = now.AddMinutes(5), // expiry can be a maximum of 6 months - generate one per request or re-use until expiration
            IssuedAt = now,
            NotBefore = now,
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa), SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
        });
    }
}
```

**The action calling the challenge**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult AppleLogin()
{
    return Challenge("apple");
}
```

**UPDATE**
Following Martin's comment, I explored a different angle following his blog article and sample application, and replacing my variables in still resulted in the same error. So I have pasted below screenshots of the AppleDeveloper console which might provide a clue, but it all looks Ok to me!

*This shows the ServicesID setup, which gets used as the ClientID in the OAuth provider (1)*

[image]

- This shows the service is linked to a primary app (This uses a different bundle identifier of course) *

[image]

*This shows the TeamID being used, in both the original post and Martin's link (2)*

[image]

*This shows the keyID which is present in the .p8 file (I know this is the right ID as if I change the name or the content of the file I get a different error)*

[image]

Edit: I've been trying all sorts of methods to no avail. Is there any other documentation anyone can point me towards?

Comment: I have a [sample application](https://github.com/martincostello/SignInWithAppleSample/tree/main/src/SignInWithApple) built on top of [this provider](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Apple) that I know is working - maybe compare the two implementations to see if something sticks out.

Comment: Thanks @MartinCostello. I;ve pulled your sample code, put my p8 file in and popped my variables into the `AddApple` section, but I get the same "`invalid_client` error. So there msut be something up with the variables I am using. `options.ClientId` is the Identifier from Service ID in Apple Developer. `options.Keyid' is the ID of the .p8 file. `options.TeamId` is my team id from the developer portal. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I've updated the OP @MartinCostello with some screens from the Apple Developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing more digging I came across a post that suggested I pass in the KeyId to the Signing credentials.

```
SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa){KeyId = keyId},
SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
``
```